# How to round to units of thousands or millions, etc., in a table column?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table with lots of raw numbers in the billions and hundreds of millions. I'd like to abbreviate the figures in these columns to millions. So instead of `234,091,123` as per the input, I'd like to display `234.09` without having to change the raw figures.

(I can then manually add the unit `(m)` to the column header.)

For example, I'd like to go automatically...

**FROM:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.},group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=9.0]}
\textbf{String} & \textbf{Number}\\
A & 123,456,789\\
B & 1,234,098\\
{...} & {...}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: from]

**TO:**

[image]

I might have overlooked something, but I didn't find anything in `siunitx`. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the fact that `siunitx` has a setting to drop exponents in tables here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-decimal-markers = ., input-ignore = {,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
  {
    l
    S[fixed-exponent = 6, table-omit-exponent,table-format = 3.2, table-auto-round]
  }
\textbf{String} & \textbf{Number}\\
A & 123,456,789\\
B & 1,234,098\\
{...} & {...}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You have of course to make some decisions yourself!

Comment: Was thinking the exponent notation could be useful. :) Great, thanks again!

Comment: What about outside of a table?